# filter date from a string JULIA

Tags: dataframe, datetime, parsing, julia, feather

I have the next format for my date in my dataframe:

```
Typeof(DateTime("2021-12-17T06:00:00"))
Feather.Arrow.Timestamp{Microsecond}
```

I want to filter the data by date, but I can't because of the type. I tried to chop it, but again because of the type I couldn't.

```
MethodError: no method matching chop(::Feather.Arrow.Timestamp{Microsecond}; head=10, tail=2)
Closest candidates are:
  chop(::AbstractString; head, tail) at strings/util.jl:184
```

So I tried to change the type using parse but it is not allowed.
In R, I use filter and face no problem.
What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your question when you want to clarify or add things, don't put it into an "answer".

Comment: How did you create the data frame? What external packages may have been used?

Comment: Agreed with @AndreWildberg . It's difficult and pointless to try to solve this further without a [Minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) code.

Answer (score 0):

To filter a DataFrame's row by value, see the [Subsetting section of the DataFrames manual](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/latest/man/working_with_dataframes/#Subsetting-functions).

```
julia> df = DataFrame(n = 1:16, dates = DateTime("2021-12-17T06:00:00"):Day(1):DateTime("2022-01-01T06:00:00"));

julia> summary(df)
"16×2 DataFrame"

julia> df[DateTime("2021-12-25") .<= df.dates .<= DateTime("2021-12-31"), :]
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ n      dates               
     │ Int64  DateTime            
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     9  2021-12-25T06:00:00
   2 │    10  2021-12-26T06:00:00
   3 │    11  2021-12-27T06:00:00
   4 │    12  2021-12-28T06:00:00
   5 │    13  2021-12-29T06:00:00
   6 │    14  2021-12-30T06:00:00

julia> #OR:

julia> datefilter(dates) = DateTime("2021-12-25") .<= dates .<= DateTime("2021-12-31")
datefilter (generic function with 1 method)

julia> subset(df, :dates => datefilter)
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ n      dates               
     │ Int64  DateTime            
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     9  2021-12-25T06:00:00
   2 │    10  2021-12-26T06:00:00
   3 │    11  2021-12-27T06:00:00
   4 │    12  2021-12-28T06:00:00
   5 │    13  2021-12-29T06:00:00
   6 │    14  2021-12-30T06:00:00
```

For the specifics of what you want to accomplish here, it's most useful if you can show us the actual code you've tried and what its intended purpose is. (`chop` in Julia is used to process strings. tidyr-type `chop` may be replaced by `groupby`s instead, but that again depends on what your end goal here is.)

Comment: Thank u, but I didn´t make myself clear before. My DataFrame has different type as yours. I think I make it clearer down.